# responsive height matching with jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize, height

I have a jQuery function for finding the tallest div with a selector and applying that height to all divs of the same selector. That's nothing new - works great on (document).ready. I'm trying to get the same function to run on (window).resize but it's not.

```
jQuery(document).ready(loadheight);
jQuery(window).resize(loadheight);
function loadheight(){
    maxHeight = 0;
    boxes = jQuery('.item');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
        Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return jQuery(this).height();
    }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
}
```

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecuQW/

I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Thoughts?

Comment: when you set it on ready, the heights are set.. 
so when you resize, you get the height you set before.. 
your script is working, what do you try exactly?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working as is.

Comment: Whats not working? Comment out `jQuery(document).ready(loadheight);` (i.e. bind it only to onresize) and you'll see that its working as expected on resize as well.

Comment: Thanks guys for checking this out. I'm unfortunately not getting it to work on the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ecuQW/. For example, when you see the blue boxes in one column (result window less than 767px) and "run" the Fiddle, it's good, but when you resize the result box to greater than 767px, the content box for the largest div (div 3) is cutting off the text. This happens even with the document.ready line commented out as techfoobar suggested. Thanks!